# 0cx000021a BSOD

Tags: windows-10, security, bsod, cmd.exe

I am having this windows BSOD problem that won't let me boot.

I have restored, booted on safe mode, disabled signature on boot, I tried out cmd `sfc/scannow` (which did not work), I also renamed the configure files (DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE) and now I am frustrated, I really do not know what to do next.

I even tried to reset my PC last night and the error prevented the reset, so am I doomed?

I really have to use my PC, what can I do?

The problem occurred after the shutdown took longer than it used to.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest before booting up, hit f8 and then select repair computer. Or you can put in the disc drive your windows install disc, if you have one and then repair computer from there.

Also, microsoft has a page specifically for this error.

[Bug Check 0xC000021A](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560177(v=vs.85).aspx)

according to the page the most likely problem is third party applications or device drivers. So its possible that its not your windows install causing this problem, but more or less a faulty application or driver